# have a question already asked but witout reply

Tags: support, asking-questions

Hi

I have a question that has already been asked 4 moths ago. The author was asked to explain more his problem, but he didn't, so the topic was abbadoned.

I have the same problem and I can try to explain more on what it consist. Should I create a new thread or continue the old one? And if the second is rigth - how should I do it?

The thread in question is: [Arabic reading error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6485/arabic-reading-error).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would edit the question and add more information to it if it is 100% the same problem you are facing.

A >10k user will see your edit request and approve it if it is OK. That will boost the question to the front page where it gets attention.

Comment: i would create a  new question since maria will be able to accept the correct answer and not wait for adding more information in the question.